# JAVA проверка новых версий

Tags: java

Есть программа написанная на JAVA. Jar файл обернут Launch4j и сделан инсталятор Inno Setup. Как можно реализовать проверку на новую версию при запуске программы и автоматическое скачивание и установка новой версии пользователю?

Comment: Не знаю как сейчас, но лет 7 назад Java Web Start красиво решал проблему и с распространением, и с обновлением.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Берешь сайт свой, или место где можно положить файл и что бы к нему был прямой доступ (GoogleDrive и прочее не подойдут). Пишешь в нем номер версии или как название файла делаешь. Когда программа запускается она обращается на этот файл и сравнивает свою версию и ту что получила.
2. Если есть свой сервер сбд и прочим, то делаешь запрос на сервер за версией.

С файлом это самое распространённое.

Ну скачать думаю тоже проблем нет - Код. А вот с запуском его. Можно через `exec` команду в джаве - она выполняет команду как из `cmd` консоли винды, к примеру. Та программа запускается и ищет старую, и удаляет.

```
package ua.com.prologistic;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;

public class DownloadFileFromURL {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // будем качать карту сайта моего сайта - в вашем случае замените ссылку на свою
        String url = "http://javadevblog.com/sitemap.xml";

        try {
            // качаем файл с помощью NIO
            downloadUsingNIO(url, "/Users/prologistic/sitemapnio.xml");

            // качаем файл с помощью Stream
            downloadUsingStream(url, "/Users/prologistic/sitemap_stream.xml");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // качаем файл с помощью Stream
    private static void downloadUsingStream(String urlStr, String file) throws IOException{
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int count=0;
        while((count = bis.read(buffer,0,1024)) != -1)
        {
            fis.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        fis.close();
        bis.close();
    }

    // качаем файл с помощью NIO
    private static void downloadUsingNIO(String urlStr, String file) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(url.openStream());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
        fos.close();
        rbc.close();
    }

}
```

[Источник](https://javadevblog.com/kak-skachat-fajl-v-java.html)